Given an unbiased estimator, prove that all unbiased estimators are that estimator minus any estimator with expectation zero
Lehmann (Theory of Point Estimation second edition, Lemma 1.4) doesn't prove this statement, because he says it is obvious. I would like a proof.
If $\delta_0$ is any unbiased estimator of $g(\theta)$, the totality of unbiased estimators is given by $\delta=\delta_0-U$ where $U$ is any unbiased estimator of zero, that is, it satisfies $E_\theta(U)=0$ for all $\theta \in \Omega$.
My proof attempts:

Prove that all unbiased estimators $\delta_k$ of $g(\theta)$ have the same functional form.
I don't know how to do that.

Use moments:


$\forall \delta_0, \delta_1 \exists U$
$\forall i\in\{1,2,\dots\}, E[\delta_0^i]=E[(\delta_1+U)^i]$
$E[\delta_0^i]=\sum_{j=0}^i \binom{i}{j} E[\delta_1^{i-j}U^i]$
Maybe this could work as the number of equations equals the number of unknowns (moments of $U$).

Different unbiased estimators can have different functional forms.  Take for example a Poisson distribution  with parameter $\lambda$ (the mean) and the observations $X_1$ and $X_2$.  Then $X_1$ and $\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}$  and $\frac{(X_1+1)^2 - (X_2-1)^2}{4}$  are all unbiased estimators  of $\lambda$, though the third is a particularly bad one and can often produce negative estimates, particularly when $\lambda$ is large.

It is linearity of expectation (a consequence of the linearity of the Lebesgue integral).

$E_\theta[\delta_0-U] = E_\theta[\delta_0] - E_\theta[U]$.

$\delta_0$ is an unbiased estimator of $g(\theta)$ when $E_\theta[\delta_0] =g(\theta)$.

$U$ is an unbiased estimator of $0$ when $E_\theta[U] =0$.


Putting these together, if $\delta_0$ is any unbiased estimator of $g(\theta)$ and $U$ is any unbiased estimator of $0$ for each possible $\theta$, then
$$E_\theta[\delta_0-U] = E_\theta[\delta_0] - E_\theta[U] = g(\theta)-0=g(\theta).$$
Similarly if $\delta_0$ and $\delta$ are any unbiased estimators of $g(\theta)$ and $U=\delta_0-\delta$ then $E_\theta[U] = E_\theta[\delta_0-\delta] = E_\theta[\delta_0] - E_\theta[\delta] = g(\theta)-g(\theta)=0$, so $U$ is an unbiased estimator of $0$ with $\delta = \delta_0-U$.
